# Error serving static content Dropwziard

Tags: java, rest, dropwizard

I'm serving static assets in dropwizard, just a basic AssetBundle inside my application initialize method. [1.3 DW serving static assets](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.0/docs/manual/core.html#serving-assets).

`bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets/", "/assets"));`

My static assets are located in `src/main/resources/assets/`

For now, there's just an `.html` file that I want to serve at `localhost:port/assets/index.html`.

When I go to `localhost:port/assets/index.html` I seem to be getting a weird `jetty-server` error.

```
org.eclipse.jetty.util.SharedBlockingCallback: Blocker not complete Blocker@6aa2d91b{null}
WARN  [2018-05-02 19:10:32,492] org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler: Error for /assets/MultiFileUpload.html
! java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.http.GzipHttpContent
! at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
! at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
! at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
! at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
! ... 43 common frames omitted
! Causing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/http/GzipHttpContent
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHttpOutputInterceptor.commit(GzipHttpOutputInterceptor.java:229)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHttpOutputInterceptor.write(GzipHttpOutputInterceptor.java:104)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:235)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:219)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.close(HttpOutput.java:269)
! at io.dropwizard.servlets.assets.AssetServlet.doGet(AssetServlet.java:197)
! at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
! at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.NonblockingServletHolder.handle(NonblockingServletHolder.java:49)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1772)
! at io.dropwizard.servlets.ThreadNameFilter.doFilter(ThreadNameFilter.java:35)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.handle(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:45)
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.doFilter(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:39)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
! at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:239)
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.RoutingHandler.handle(RoutingHandler.java:52)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:493)
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.BiDiGzipHandler.handle(BiDiGzipHandler.java:69)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:56)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:169)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:283)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:108)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:240)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:283)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:108)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
! at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [02/May/2018:19:10:32 +0000] "GET /assets/index.html HTTP/1.1" 500 265 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36" 27
```

I've read [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33935866/dropwizard-assets-not-serving-static-content-outside-of-root-path) that it may be a better idea to use [DropwizardViews](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/tree/master/dropwizard-views)
Although, I'm not sure what the issue is with the gziphttpContent class that's causing the error in jetty.

Comment: I've had issues with dropwizard+gzip before, the browser may be adding some Accept headers that allow zipped content.  What happens if you `curl -v` the same URL?

Comment: It doesn't seem to cause an issue when accessing my api endpoints, just specifically this static file for whatever reason. Is there a way to disallow zipped content in the app config file? I believe I read that somewhere in the docs.

Comment: That is why I'm suggesting examining the request headers, perhaps the browser is adding something that is causing this error.  If you use `curl http://localhost:port/assets/index.html` what happens, same error?

Comment: for context: I have a TLS connection so my browser is using a self signed cert. Using `curl -k -v https://localhost:port/assets/index.html` it seems to accept the request and shows the html view of the `index.html` file.

Comment: If it works with curl but not in the browser I'll bet that your browser is adding `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header to the request without you knowing it.  See [this issue](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/1313).  It is unlikely that this is related to TLS.

Comment: `Vary: Accept-Encoding` indeed is shown as part of the accepted request by curl. I'll give the issue a look. Thanks. It looks like that issue wasn't persistent through the newer versions of DW. I will try disabling gzip in my config file.

Comment: Try adding `server: gzip: enabled: false` in your dropwizard config file, and see if it works in the browser

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks for the pointers, probably saved me a few days. Didn't think to use curl to check if there was anything getting added to the header requests. The stack trace makes a little more sense now ... Make an answer response and I'll gladly accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing the comment thread in an answer in a shameless bid for reputation :)

Gzip is an encoding strategy used in HTTP requests.  Most likely, your browser is adding the `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header to the request.  For whatever reason, dropwizard is unable to gzip the contents of the response, and that's the stack trace you've posted.

To check whether the browser might be adding this header, you can use

`curl -vk https://localhost:<port>/assets/index.html`

to make the same request, and see if you get the same exception.  If not, then it is likely the browser is asking for gzipped content, which dropwizard is unable to provide.  To determine this definitively, you can use a sniffing tool like Wireshark or Charles Proxy to examine the full HTTP request that your browser is making.

As a workaround, you can disable gzip in the dropwizard server config:

```
server:
  gzip:
    enabled: false
```

This should do the trick, although it is not necessarily an optimal solution.  I don't know whether the root cause is a bug in dropwizard or something to do with the gzip configuration.